# Firebase inner query in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am new to Firebase. I am now trying to perform a query against my collections but I do not know how. I have the logged in user (after log in I have his Id), Category, and Purchase collections.

Category collection has an userId column, and Purchase has CategoryId.

Having the userId, how can I query Purchase collection for that user? I should somehow do a kind of inner join between Purchase and Category where Category.UserId is equals to the UserId I have.

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my current code, but it is not working:

```
fetchAllPurchaseHistory(userId: string) {
    this.fetchCategories()
    const userDocRef = firebase.firestore()
        .collection('User')
        .doc(userId);

    const categoriesDocRef = firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Category').where('UserId', '==', userDocRef);

    this.fbSubs.push(this.db.collection('Purchase', ref => ref.where('CategoryId', '==', categoriesDocRef))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
            return {
                Id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                UserId: doc.payload.doc.data()['UserId'],
                Description: doc.payload.doc.data()['Description'],
                Address: doc.payload.doc.data()['Address'],
                Establishment: doc.payload.doc.data()['Establishment'],
                Price: doc.payload.doc.data()['Price'],
                CreatedDate: doc.payload.doc.data()['CreatedDate']
            };
        });
        })).subscribe((ps: Purchase[]) => {
            this.store.dispatch(new Finance.SetPurchaseHistory(ps));                
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't have an Inner join query out-of-the-box so to make this kind of query you'll need to query the documents one by one to extract the necessary information to query the next one and so on, in fact doing the join code-wise.

One thing that is not clear to me is whether the values UserId in Category collection and CategoryId in Purchase collection are document id's or document references. Assuming they're document ids the code may look like:

```
// Assume db is a firestore instance
function foo(userId) {
    const categoryDoc = await db.collection('Category').where('UserId', '==', userId).get()
    const categoryId = categoryDoc.id
    const purchaseDoc = await db.collection('Purchase').where('CategoryId', '==', categoryId).get()
    // Do whatever you need with the document
}
```

Separately, upon reading your description I believe you come from a SQL background and you're emulating the relations between tables with document fields holding the others document references. While this approach is useful to model 1-Many or Many-1 relations, if you see that simple daily usage queries require multiple document cross-references it usually means the database should be structured differently.

For instance some common approaches are:

- Let the user document have a subcollection of categories or purchases so that you can reference them directly through the userId.
- Let the purchase document have a field with the userId (maybe categoryId also) so that it could be found with a single query.
- Inline the purchase document in the user document. This may be good/bad depending on the data to be stored and how it may be updated

For more information on this topic you may take a look at the videos from Firebase channel that could be found in Youtube or in this documentation [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)